# Send buffer stream to Icecast server using jshout in Java

Tags: java, shoutcast, icecast, internet-radio

I am trying to develop live streaming using Icecast or SHOUTcast library.

I recorded audio in Java, and I need to send a byte stream to the Icecast Server.

Comment: You've recorded audio, but have you ran it through a codec?  Once you've done that, Thomas' response below is correct.  You can simply use any HTTP library to send a PUT request, and then stream the data to it.

Comment: here is my code that i am using, but its causes an error
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.gmail.kunicins.olegs.libshout.Libshout;


public class SendingStream {

 
 
 static Libshout libshout;
 
 {
  try{
   
   libshout = new Libshout();
   System.out.println("Version is : "+libshout.getVersion());

   
  }catch(Exception ee){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error while setting detail to shouter : "+ee);
  }
  
 }
 
 public static void main(String args[]){
  
  
  new SendingStream();
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

http://icecast.org/download/#bindings 
lists:
https://github.com/OlegKunitsyn/libshout-java

Have you tried that yet?
Also if you can just send a HTTP PUT request followed by a body *without* chunked encoding, you'd be home free for the most basic use case. (PUT requires Icecast 2.4 or newer)

Comment: please do a favor for me, i tried but i not found libshout 2.2.2 jar file, so please if you suggest me a link

Comment: The github page states how to build that jar.

Comment: here is my sample code that i am trying to run but it causes an error
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.gmail.kunicins.olegs.libshout.Libshout;


public class SendingStream {


 
 static Libshout libshout;
 
 {
  try{
   
   libshout = new Libshout();
   System.out.println("Version is : "+libshout.getVersion());

   
  }catch(Exception ee){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error while setting detail to shouter : "+ee);
  }
  
 }
 
 public static void main(String args[]){
  
  
  new SendingStream();
 }
}

Comment: I haven't used Java in Years. I just replied because I'm a) the Icecast maintainer, b) knew that there is a java binding.