# How to send title & artist name with audio using icecast client in android

Tags: android, metadata, icecast

Following code works as expected for up streaming to icecast server. But I want to send extra information like title, artist along with stream. I have tried by adding tags like ice-title,ice-artist,title, artist. But it's not adding title & artist

```
s = new Socket(server,port_num);
Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");
out =  new BufferedOutputStream(new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));
Log.d("VS", "Output Stream Established");
output = new PrintWriter(out);
Log.d("VS", "Send Header");
output.println("SOURCE /"+mountpoint+" ICE/2.0");
output.println("Authorization: Basic "+authString);
output.println("ice-name:"+title);
output.println("ice-url:echonet.cc");
output.println("TITLE="+title);
output.println("ARTIST="+generalUsername);
output.println("ice-username:"+generalUsername); 
output.println("ice-user:"+generalUsername);
output.println("content-type: application/x-ogg");
output.println("User-Agent: App");                  
output.println("ice-private: 0");
output.println("ice-public: 1");
output.println("ice-audio-info: ice-samplerate="+sampleRate_string+"ice-quality="+quality_string+";ice-channels="+channel_string);
output.println("ice-audio-info: ice-samplerate=8000;ice-bitrate=128;ice-channels=2");
output.println("\r\n");
output.println("\n");
output.flush();
Log.d("VS", "Header sent");
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
   if (line.equals("")) break;
   Log.d("VS", "Responce From Server");
   Log.d("VS",line);
}
```

I am very new to android programming. If there is any problem in code or any other way to send title & artist please let me know. Thanks

Comment: This looks very very wrong. Just use libshout bindings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28192505/2648865

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solved issue** by modifying native code.

I have added extra parameter in start method of vorbis recorder & accordingly modified other functions.
Added extra parameter for artist in org_xiph_vorbis_encoder_VorbisEncoder.c & org_xiph_vorbis_encoder_VorbisEncoder.h 
in order to get title & artist work.

There is method 
    **vorbis_comment_add_tag(&vc,"Artist","your extra parameter");** 
in org_xiph_vorbis_encoder_VorbisEncoder.c so we just have to pass parameter to it.